# Swift MapKit MKDirections Memory Leak on Calculate

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am working with MapKit in SwiftUI and having a memory leaks when using the devices location with `.calculate()` on `MKDirections`. According to the Leaks Instrument in Xcode I have a Malloc memory leak with variable size depending on how far the locations are from one another on each `.calculate()` call.

Here is my minimal code example

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var myText: String = ""
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(myText)
        .onAppear() {
            calculateDistancefrom(doneSearching: { distance,error  in
                myText = String(distance)
            })
        }
    }
    .padding()
}
}

// MapKit function
func calculateDistancefrom(doneSearching: @escaping (_ distance: CLLocationDistance, _ error: String) -> Void) {
let request: MKDirections.Request = MKDirections.Request()

request.departureDate = Date()
request.arrivalDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(1))

let location = CLLocationManager()

// ASK TO ALLOW LOCATION
if (location.authorizationStatus != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse &&
    location.authorizationStatus != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways){
    location.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}

let deviceLocation = location.location?.coordinate

// MUST USE DEVICE LOCATION TO GET MEMORY LEAK
request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: deviceLocation!))
request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: 
CLLocation.init(latitude: NSString(string: "36.073").doubleValue, longitude: 
NSString(string: "-79.792").doubleValue).coordinate))

request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
request.transportType = .automobile

let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

//THIS .calculate() LEAKS A Malloc 64 BYTES ?????
directions.calculate(completionHandler: { (directions, error) in
    doneSearching(1, "do nothing")
})
}
```

Comment: Does `weak self` make a difference?

Comment: @matt Thanks, I tired `weak self`, but still have the leak :/

Comment: Well, I'd just ignore it. You could leak 64 bytes a lot of times and not even notice.

Comment: Try converting to async await

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks, tried async await, but still have the leak :/